# Typescript and google maps API data return

Tags: javascript

I have a function returning some data from googlemaps API and I'm having a hard time trying to get only an specific part of it.

this is the data returned by google:

```
{"address_components":[{"long_name":"200","short_name":"200","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Carrer de Mallorca","short_name":"Carrer de Mallorca","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Barcelona","short_name":"Barcelona","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Barcelona","short_name":"Barcelona","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Catalunya","short_name":"CT","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Spain","short_name":"ES","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"08026","short_name":"08026","types":["postal_code"]}],"adr_address":"<span class=\"street-address\">Carrer de Mallorca, 200</span>, <span class=\"postal-code\">08026</span> <span class=\"locality\">Barcelona</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Spain</span>","formatted_address":"Carrer de Mallorca, 200, 08026 Barcelona, Spain","geometry":{"location":{"lat":41.39021249999999,"lng":2.158042900000055},"viewport":{"south":41.3889164697085,"west":2.156613219708561,"north":41.3916144302915,"east":2.1593111802915246}},"icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png","id":"ed44ea26f2c7aea2a9c892b4f987060373e82716","name":"Carrer de Mallorca, 200","place_id":"ChIJDZPgZSijpBIR4hLq7CXRSmE","reference":"CmRbAAAAE_RAIKFUm8Zg8rBvjoyfINpZRYf_Q_uWVFSdwKHGwIb5Bys3XFVkCX3HvTgm6L8TtC0ZsByQRqv9AcMCbEcULLys9EGcIvu6PGeqo0vQRWyy7qJqIMnuuH6dlVzidZzkEhDSiJEdUg7rIuC1aFdpUmzpGhRto1xkIFhLGky-b2vTRrCXa0jP8Q","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["street_address"],"url":"https://maps.google.com/?q=Carrer+de+Mallorca,+200,+08026+Barcelona,+Spain&ftid=0x12a4a32865e0930d:0x614ad125ecea12e2","utc_offset":60,"vicinity":"Barcelona","html_attributions":[],"description":"Carrer de Mallorca, 200, 08026 Barcelona, Spain","active":false}
```

i have "cleaned" it a bit so its easier to understand:

```
console.log(23);
{
"address_components":
[
{"long_name":"656","short_name":"656","types":["street_number"]},
{"long_name":"Carrer de Mallorca","short_name":"Carrer de Mallorca","types":["route"]},
{"long_name":"Barcelona","short_name":"Barcelona","types":["locality","political"]},
{"long_name":"Barcelona","short_name":"Barcelona","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},
{"long_name":"Catalunya","short_name":"CT","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},
{"long_name":"Spain","short_name":"ES","types":["country","political"]},
{"long_name":"08027","short_name":"08027","types":["postal_code"]}
],
"adr_address":"<span class=\"street-address\">Carrer de Mallorca, 656</span>, <span class=\"postal-code\">08027</span> <span class=\"locality\">Barcelona</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Spain</span>",

 "formatted_address": "Carrer de Mallorca, 656, 08027 Barcelona, Spain",
 "geometry":{"location":{"lat":41.4138822,"lng":2.189461700000038},
 "viewport":{"south":41.4125332197085,"west":2.1881127197084425,"north":41.41523118029149,"east":2.19081068029152}},
 "icon":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
 "id":"5fdc4f7153361cad7ec5a8a5c8de0005e7ab52fe",
 "name":"Carrer de Mallorca, 656",
 "place_id":"ChIJ9fsizS6jpBIR5TaqNaBTNf8",
 "reference":"CmRbAAAAWPvkLVHOqbDxjuKDGj6juRTKYZUd2hx6RIAzGrvPLRpJo8Nw4t04fvrUpwLIW2oNJgVAIyPheMHncgHIes5WTjB9gYIZbW2MVPf7HGsTY3XYxVsLOy_Io3CEb0h379oKEhC_w0-aX--Btb8lUMUGfHLgGhQ6NaYtk3W5TOiwIXBRUzoNxsJqJQ",
 "scope":"GOOGLE",
 "types":["street_address"],
 "url":"https://maps.google.com/?q=Carrer+de+Mallorca,+656,+08027+Barcelona,+Spain&ftid=0x12a4a32ecd22fbf5:0xff3553a035aa36e5",
 "utc_offset":60,
 "vicinity":"Barcelona",
 "html_attributions":[],
 "description":"Carrer de Mallorca, 656, 08027 Barcelona, Spain",
 "active":false

 }
```

How can I acces "url" and "description"?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the ulr and the description try this:

```
const description = 23.description;
const url = 23.url;

console.log('The description is :' + description);
console.log('The url is: ' + url);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cool, you can also access object properties using bracket notation as well. The above example would be `const url = 23['description']` this can be used if the object keys have spaces in them which would break dot notation. e.g. `const someValue = 23['Some weird formatted key']` or `const someValue = 23[useVariableValue]`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it. The Data returned is a JSON therefor is as easy as adding for example

data.url